# 404 error when doing request to a UmbracoAuthorizedApiController

Tags: c#, angularjs, umbraco

I'm having some issues trying to perform a request from a custom dashboard plugin I've setup in Umbraco CMS v12. Whenever I call the /get/ method, I get a 404 error in the backoffice. If any additional information is needed, please let me know.

App_Plugins/MyPlugin/Controllers/MyPluginController.cs:

```
namespace MyPlugin.Controllers
{
    public class MyPluginController : UmbracoAuthorizedApiController
    {     
        public MyPluginController(UmbracoDatabase database)
        {}

        [HttpGet]
        public dynamic GetTest()
        {
            dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
            settings.data = "Add your fetched data here";

            return settings;
        }
}
```

App_Plugins/MyPlugin/Controllers/myplugin.controller.js:

```
angular
    .module('umbraco')
    .controller(
        'MyPlugin.MyPluginController',
        function ($scope, MyPluginResource) {
            var vm = this
            MyPluginResource.get().then(function (response) {
                vm.data = response.data
                console.log(vm.data)
            })
        }
    )
```

App_Plugins/MyPlugin/resources/myplugin.resource.js:

```
angular
    .module('umbraco.resources')
    .factory('MyPluginResource', function ($q, $http, umbRequestHelper) {
        return {
            get: function () {
                return umbRequestHelper.resourcePromise(
                    $http.get('/backoffice/api/MyPlugin/GetTest'),
                    'Failed to fetch data'
                )
            }
        }
    })
```

App_Plugins/MyPlugin/views/myplugin.html

```
<div ng-controller="MyPlugin.MyPluginController as vm"></div>
```

Comment: The route for that endpoint would be `/backoffice/api/MyPlugin`, since you haven't specified a route parameter in the `[HttpGet]` attribute, or added a `[Route]` attribute to the method.

Comment: Found the issue finally. It was the wrong routing as you pointed out.

According to the Umbraco CMS documentation, that when creating a Plugin based controller, one needs to add a PluginController: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/umbraco-api-controllers

So adding:  [PluginController("Myplugin")] to the .cs file, then changing the get request path to: /backoffice/MyPlugin/MyPlugin/GetTest

Comment: Ah, yes. I was looking at the backoffice section of that same page, since that was the route that you had included in the post. I didn't pick up on the plugin part.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Umbraco API controller in a package, I needed to add the Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Attributes.PluginController attribute to my controller like so:

```
namespace MyPlugin.Controllers
{
    [PluginController("MyPlugin")]
    public class MyPluginController : UmbracoAuthorizedApiController
    {     
        public MyPluginController()
        {}

        [HttpGet]
        public dynamic GetTest()
        {
            dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
            settings.data = "Add your fetched data here";

            return settings;
        }
}
```

Then updated the path in myplugin.resource.js:

```
angular
    .module('umbraco.resources')
    .factory('MyPluginResource', function ($q, $http, umbRequestHelper) {
        return {
            get: function () {
                return umbRequestHelper.resourcePromise(
                    $http.get('/backoffice/MyPlugin/MyPlugin/GetTest'),
                    'Failed to fetch data'
                )
            }
        }
    })
```